# Facing error in JDBC tabe creation

Tags: java, jdbc

I have done a program using jdbc it worked fine once, first time it created the table successfully but after that it is giving error

Error is sql syntax error after ' in line 1

My code where there is error

```
String table="Create table "+tablename+"( "+rowdataa[1]+" varchar(45), "+rowdataa[2]+" varchar(45), "+rowdataa[3]+" varchar(45), "+rowdataa[4]+" varchar(45), "+a5+" varchar(45), "+a6+" varchar(45), "+a7+" varchar(45), "+rowdataa[8]+" varchar(45))";
myStmt.executeUpdate(table);
```

rowtataa is a string containing the column name

Help

Comment: Can you print the `table` variable on the console and get the output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It ran for first time then it was giving error .. its quite obvious  as the table was created one then it wouldn't be create on same name ....

use

```
String table="Create table if not exists "+tablename+"( "+rowdataa[1]+" varchar(45), "+rowdataa[2]+" varchar(45), "+rowdataa[3]+" varchar(45), "+rowdataa[4]+" varchar(45), "+a5+" varchar(45), "+a6+" varchar(45), "+a7+" varchar(45), "+rowdataa[8]+" varchar(45))";
```

myStmt.executeUpdate(table);

Answer (score 0):

Your error says that it's a *syntax error*, so make sure that literal values in rowdataa array or in your variables (`a5`, `a6`, `a7`) do not contain any quotes or any character which is not allowed as a column identifier of your database vendor.